# Find conformal mapping that maps set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \operatorname{y\le 0}\}$ to unit ball.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find conformal mapping that maps set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :  \operatorname{y\le 0}\}$ to unit disk. I know that such a mapping exists from Riemann Theorem.

Note: I don't want full answer. I expect only some starting point hint.

Thanks

Edit:

I can use rotation by $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ on map:

$$ z \mapsto \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

So my map looks like that: $$z \mapsto e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

Edit 2:

$$z \mapsto  \frac{e^{-i\frac{\pi }{2}}z-1}{e^{-i\frac{\pi }{2}}z+1}$$

Comment: Doesn't it still require some improvement? Substituting -i gives infinity, obviously outside the unit disc.

Comment: Just realized, you have rotated the plane by 90 degrees in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map from the complex half-plane of numbers with positive real part to the unit disc is given by $$ z \mapsto \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$
For details on this see an earlier question [Mapping half-plane to unit disk?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114733/mapping-half-plane-to-unit-disk)

You should be able to modify this for you purpose; note that your set corresponds to the  half-plane with negative imaginary part.

Your attempt is good in that you can indeed compose this map with a rotation.  However, note that you have to rotate first and then use the map given above. (You did it the other way round.)

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: This is almost fine. I expanded my post and also corrected an error; but in fact you understood it the way I should have written it.

Comment: I edited my post again.

Comment: It is $e^{i \pi/2} z$ not  $e^{i \pi z/2} $. Also note that $e^{i \pi/2}=-i$ which allows for some siplification.

Comment: I see you just correct the first thing. Yes this is fine. You can further simplfy using $e^{i\pi/2}=-i$.