# conformal mapping and bilinear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I've got the next problem in complex analysis:
find the bilinear transformation from A to B:

$${A = [z: \text{Re } z \ge-1 ]},\quad  B = [w: |w|\ge1]$$

first, I tried to determine what each of the domains looks like.
As I understand it (please correct me if not), the plot of domain $A$ is all the area satisfies $x\ge-1$ (and all the y's included). The plot of domain $B$ is a closed ring with a radius of $1$, and the area covered is everything outside the circle.
Tried to take $3$ points of each boundary and plug it into the next formula:
[The formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsihO.png)

the problem is I'm getting a weird solution which does not satisfy the conditions.
thanks.

Comment: try this $z \mapsto \frac{z+3}{z-1}$, similar post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114733/mapping-half-plane-to-unit-disk

Comment: @138Aspen But how you figured it? did you take boundary points, or its something I'm missing from movius transformation?

edit: checked the post, I think I understood this way. however, I'm trying now to understand what I did wrong my checking 3 points from the plane